# Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.visualstudio.shell.ui.internal' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express, ssms-2014

[image]

While opening SQL server management studio 2014 the Following error coming

could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.visualstudio.shell.ui.internal' or one of its dependencies.Invalid pointer (exception from HRESULT:0x800004003 (E_POINTER)).

**Tried**

1. Re-installed Vs2010 shell isolated
2. Re-installed Whole SQL server package

Comment: Why not install the latest version of SSMS?

Comment: It's a windows 7 32bit OS, latest version of SSMS needs a 64 bit OS, so wanted to fix this issue

Comment: Time to switch to a supported version of Windows too then, it seems. (Extended) Support for Windows 7 ended last year